# Why do I see "sendmail: queue runner" as a process after running SOME sendmail commands but not others?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

I'm in the process of trying to troubleshoot some queue processing issues in SendMail and am confused on why I'm seeing references in `ps` output following SOME sendmail commands but not others.

I have a 8.14.x sendmail server and I presently have a couple operations going on:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -L Foo_Instance -Ac -q 5m -C /etc/foo/mail/Foo_Instance/submit.cf
```

When I launch this, and then check running processes, I see:

```
root      7642  0.0  0.0   9400  1736 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     7650  0.0  0.0   8348  1528 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@00:05:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
101       7668  0.0  0.0   8348  1536 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@00:05:00 for /var/spool/mqueue-foo/Foo_Instance/msp
root      7671  0.0  0.0   4028   668 pts/0    R+   18:20   0:00 grep sendmail
```

That's all fine I suppose, but if I stop everything and I run:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bd -q5m -L Foo_Instance -C /etc/foo/mail/Foo_Instance/sendmail.cf
```

...and then check running processes, I see:

```
root      7823  0.0  0.0   9404  1740 ?        Ss   18:24   0:00 sendmail: accepting connections                                                      
root      7830  0.0  0.0   4028   688 pts/0    R+   18:25   0:00 grep sendmail
```

The key difference here being that I don't see "Queue runner" in the ps output. Why don't I see separate processes both time? Or neither time?

Even if I don't see the queue runner process, I see indications in the logs that the queues are being retried.

At first, I thought it might be happening because have an erroneous space after `-q`.  But the behavior still happens even if I run

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -L Foo_Instance -Ac -q5m -C /etc/foo/mail/Foo_Instance/submit.cf
```

I thought that perhaps "Queue runner@xx:xx:xx" could be an indication that the queue runner is a persistent queue runner but the batbook indicates that a persistent runner process would have the word "running" in it:

```
root 22947 512 ? S 08:32 0:00 sendmail: running queue: /var/spool/mqueues/
q.1/df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sendmail -bd -q5m` starts main daemon process  (`sendmail: accepting connections`). The daemon process will spawn queue runner process for one time queue run **when needed**.
2. You need separate command to start client-queue runner process (`sendmail: Queue runner@00:05:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue`). The client-queue runner behavior is controlled by `submit.cf` not by `sendmail.cf`.
   [Some setups use periodic "single run" cron jobs to process client-queue instead of permanent queue runners]